# Quartz 2.2.3 JobStore Property Being Overriden by Default Settings - Spring Boot, Liquibase, Oracle

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, liquibase

I am trying to implement a Quartz scheduler in my Spring Boot application; however, I continue to receive the following error after startup:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "SCHED_NAME": invalid identifier.
```

In the startup logs before the error, I see:

```
liquibase                                : Successfully acquired change log lock
liquibase                                : Reading from PARTSVOICE_APP.DATABASECHANGELOG
liquibase                                : Successfully released change log lock
o.q.i.StdSchedulerFactory                : Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
o.q.c.SchedulerSignalerImpl              : Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
o.q.c.QuartzScheduler                    : Quartz Scheduler v.2.2.3 created.
o.s.s.q.LocalDataSourceJobStore          : Using db table-based data access locking (synchronization).
o.s.s.q.LocalDataSourceJobStore          : JobStoreCMT initialized.
o.q.c.QuartzScheduler                    : Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.2.3) 'scheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 25 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore' - which supports persistence. and is not clustered.
```

This message is concerning because in my application.yml, my setup is the following:

```
org:
  quartz:
    scheduler:
      instanceName: cdp-scheduler
      instanceId: AUTO
    threadPool:
      threadCount: 25
      class: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
    jobStore:
      class: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
      tablePrefix: c_
```

I read these properties and put them within a SchedulerFactoryBean here:

```
 @Bean
public SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler(DataSource ds, SpringLiquibase dependent) throws SchedulerException, ConnectionException {
    SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    Properties quartzProps = new Properties();
    quartzProps.setProperty("org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId", quartzConfig.getInstanceId());
    quartzProps.setProperty("org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName", quartzConfig.getInstanceName());
    quartzProps.setProperty("org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount", quartzConfig.getThreadCount());
    quartzProps.setProperty("org.quartz.jobStore.class", quartzConfig.getJobStoreClass());
    quartzProps.setProperty("org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass", "org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate");
    quartzProps.setProperty("org.quartz.threadPool.class", quartzConfig.getThreadPoolClass());
    factory.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
    factory.setAutoStartup(false);
    factory.setDataSource(ds);
    factory.setQuartzProperties(quartzProps);
    factory.setExposeSchedulerInRepository(true);
    factory.setAutoStartup(true);

    AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
    jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    factory.setJobFactory(jobFactory);

    return factory;
}
```

I am trying to use the org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX class so that I can store the Quartz information in our database. However, I believe this is getting overridden from what I can see from the log message above. A quick Google search has shown me that if you provide a datasource, then the JobStoreCMT class is automatically implemented but that doesn't make sense to me.

I'm also using Liquibase to execute a SQL script that creates the quartz tables, this is being executed fine, it drops and creates the tables I need. I've also tried using Flybase but I get the same error, so it definitely is related to my quartz setup.

Has anybody had a similar experience? Any suggestions? Please let me know if you think I should supply more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the error I can infer that the tables aren't properly created (either not at all or using the wrong scripts). For `Quartz`, you need to create the tables using the db scripts for you database type, which you can find in the quartz [download](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/tree/master/database/tables).

Here is a similar case: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/axonframework/IlWZ0UHK2hk

If you think that the script is OK, please try to create the table directly in your database.

In case that it still does not work you can go to the next step and check the configuration. Maybe the `tablePrefix` that you are using is not well interpreted. Try to use the default `QRTZ_`.

Here is an setup example with a lower version of `Quartz`.

http://www.opencodez.com/java/quartz-scheduler-with-spring-boot.htm

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I confirmed that I can run my Oracle SQL script on our databases in a separate environment like SQL Developer. I've also confirmed that Liquibase can delete and create those tables from the application. I'm thinking that I might have permissions issue so I will check with our DBA's tomorrow about the issue and get back to you. Thanks for reaching out.

Comment: Still no luck. Let me know if I should provide more information. Something is definitely wrong. Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to answer without the code. Did you try to use the default tablePrefix?. By the way, there is a demo here https://github.com/davidkiss/spring-boot-quartz-demo with liquibase too. The only difference, again, is the version of Quartz, 2.2.1.

Comment: Also, check this too. If you set the database in SchedulerFactoryBean this will override corresponding settings in Quartz properties. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SchedulerFactoryBean.html#setDataSource-javax.sql.DataSource-

Comment: Hey Cata. It turns out that you were correct, the tables were not being created properly. When specifiying the Quartz tablePrefix property, it's important to note that you need to add the schema, the prefix, and the QRTZ part. For example, in my case, my tablePrefix needed to be set as PARTSVOICE_APP.C_QRTZ_. Thanks for the help!